# Convert SQL Server Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, formatting, format

I'm using this query:

```
select convert(nvarchar(MAX), getdate(), 100);
```

It's returning

```
Aug 16 2018  3:45PM
```

I'm trying to get this date format instead:

```
16 AUG 15:45
```

Please help me achieve it. Thanks

Comment: you don't want year ?

Comment: Why does 01:38 **AM** become 13:38? AM is morning, not afternoon.

Comment: @AmitKumar yes, not year.

Comment: Different values now since I last commented, why does 3:45 PM become 14:45? Is it always an hour before?

Comment: @Larnu please check latest edit.

Comment: yes, I've made a further comment since.

Comment: Which sql server version you are using bcoz most of the answers based on "Format" function which will not work below 2012 version.

Comment: @Ramji Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul 24 2018 14:38:12   Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: with format function

```
SELECT upper(FORMAT( getdate(), 'dd MMM HH:mm', 'en-US'))
```

Comment: how can i change `Aug` as `AUG` ?

Comment: Look at the UPPER() function.

Comment: try this : upper(FORMAT( getdate(), 'dd MMM HH:mm', 'en-US' ) )

Comment: can i get without using upper() ?

Comment: as far my knowledge using format function only , not possible, you've to use upper.

Answer (score 2):

This gets you what you want, and without using the awfully slow `FORMAT` function:

```
SELECT D, CONVERT(varchar(6),DATEADD(HOUR, -1, D),13) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(5),CONVERT(time(0),DATEADD(HOUR, -1, D)),14)
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime2(0),'2018-08-16T15:45:00'))) V(d);
```

*Edit: Seems the OP moved the goals posts **again** (initially they wanted the time changed from 01:38 AM to 13:38, and then 03:45 PM to 14:45), and as a result `DATEADD` isn't required. I haven't bothered removing this though, as it was correct at the time; and I don't trust the goal posts won't move again.*

Answer (score 1):

use `upper`  and '`dd MMM HH:mm', 'en-US'` format

```
SELECT Upper( FORMAT( getdate(), 'dd MMM HH:mm', 'en-US' ))

it reutrns 16 AUG 11:03
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes thank you i have added could you please change now your down vote

Comment: can i get without using `upper()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**upper case 'Aug' to 'AUG'**

```
SELECT UPPER( FORMAT( GETUTCDATE(), 'dd MMM HH:mm', 'en-US' ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Query:

```
select UPPER(FOrmat(GETDATE(),'dd MMM HH:mm'))
```

Result:
16 AUG 17:04

[image]